# Operator Overloading: subtraction with binary '-' no global operator found which takes type _____ (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, computer-science

I'm trying to write a code that calculates the registration fee by reading from a file using eof(). However, when I try to compile I get one error, which is C2677, which means that binary "-" no global operator found. I've looked into how to fix it, but I'm not understanding. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    string VIN, make, model, type, year;
    string truck = "TRUCK";
    double basefee, weight;
    double tax = 0.065;
    double highwayfund = 2.0;
    int age;
    double discount;

    inFile.open("VehicleInput.txt");
    outFile.open("VehicleOutput.txt");

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        inFile >> VIN >> make >> model >> type >> year;
        inFile >> weight;
        age = (2020 - year);
        weight = 12000;
        discount = (age * 0.1);

        if (age >= 7)
        {
            discount = 0.7;
        }

        if ((type == "CAR") || (type == "SUV"))
        {
            basefee = (100 - ((100.0 * tax) - (100 * discount)) + highwayfund);
        }
        if (type == "BUS")
        {
            basefee = (200 - ((200.0 * tax) - (200 * discount)) + highwayfund);
        }
        if (type == "TRUCK")
        {
            basefee = (500 - ((500.0 * (0.22 + tax)) - (500 * discount)) + highwayfund);
        }


        outFile << " " << VIN << " " << make << " " << model << " " << year;
        if (weight > 12000) outFile << weight;
        outFile << "$ " << basefee << endl;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the exact error message which includes the line number plz.  That said, the problem is you made ``year`` a string which cannot be 'negated' or 'subtracted'.

Comment: The exact error message was the title of this post and it was line 29. That helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: In this line -> `age = (2020 - year);`, you try to subtract year which is a string from an int which is not possible..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
age = (2020 - year);
```

`age` is an `int`. `2020` is an int. `year` you declared as a string.

```
string VIN, make, model, type, year;
int age;
```

That's exactly what the error is telling you. There is no `operator-` which takes an `int` and `string`.